# Using a stylus pen in a webpage library functions

Tags: web-apps, library

I am hoping to find out if there are any libraries that could make it possible to embed a stylus pen sketch pad in a web page. I am hoping that there is a plugin or well elaborated library functions that could be used to construct a sketch pad within a webpage.